# Mysql data truncated after single quote in select list

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have some part numbers containing a single quote (') in a Mysql database, for example, 1234'xyz. I have an HTML page with a rather lengthy form, including a select list that will display the part numbers correctly with the single quote. However, following a form POST, if the part number contains a single quote, that  part number is displayed such that all characters following the single quote are truncated. In the case above, the part number will display 1234.

This is how I escape the form inputs and post the form:

```
array_walk_recursive( $_POST, 'mysqli_real_escape_string' ); //escape the array
$array = array_filter($_POST);  //remove empty values from the array

//---- convert key/values to string to insert as column names/values to insert          

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
$value = "'$value'";
    $updates[] = "$key = $value";
            }   

$implodeArray = implode(', ', $updates);
$id=$_SESSION['Userid'];

$query = ("UPDATE Database
        SET $implodeArray
        WHERE Userid='$id'");
```

Is it possible that the form inputs are not being escaped?

Comment: is your `mysqli` connection before your `array_walk_recursive( $_POST, 'mysqli_real_escape_string' );`? Also, why do are you quoting your `$value` in a separate line - `$value = "'$value'"; $updates[] = "$key = $value";`? You could simplify it to - `$updates[] = "$key = '$value'";`

Comment: If you're using mysqli, why aren't you using placeholders and bound variables?

Comment: I'm moving in that direction, just not there yet.

Comment: Is it possible that the form inputs are not being escaped? Why don't you check?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you've checked the $_POST key=>value pairs and confirmed that the expected values are being passed through, I think your code above will probably be cancelling the effect of your '`mysqli_real_escape_string`' escaped characters, by interpolating them again in your double-quoted `"$value"`... twice! And then again interpolating the `"$implodeArray"`

TRY:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
$value = "'".$value."'";
    $updates[] = "$key = ".$value;
            }   

$implodeArray = implode(', ', $updates);
$id=$_SESSION['Userid'];

$query = ("UPDATE Database
        SET ".$implodeArray."
        WHERE Userid='$id'");
```

Hope that helps